# Why is SetWindowText not working any more?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have code that was 1st developed with Visual C++ Version 1.52 (working and self taught). A couple of years ago I adapted it with Visual Studio and got it working. I am now trying it again with Visual Studio 2022 but I can't get the SetWindowText function to work as it had. It does change the parent window title text but it is gobbledygook. I assume it's a UNICODE problem but so far haven't been able to negotiate the maze of explanation. It is set in a wizard generated MFC document. I'm including the function. Any suggestions?

```cpp
void CTICTACView::Game()
{

    CWnd* p_Wnd = GetParent();
    const char* capt = "TIC TAC TOE";
    const char* gm = "GAME!";
    if (!game)
        p_Wnd->SetWindowText((LPCTSTR)capt);
    else
        p_Wnd->SetWindowText((LPCTSTR)gm);

}
```

After constructing Frankenstein from bits and pieces, this is what I finally got to work. Thank you everybody.

```
void CTICTACView::Game()
{
  CWnd* p_Wnd = GetParent();    
  const wchar_t* capt =_T("TIC TAC TOE");
  const wchar_t* gm = _T("GAME!");
  if (!game)
    p_Wnd->SetWindowText((LPCWSTR)capt);
  else
    p_Wnd->SetWindowText((LPCWSTR)gm);
}
```

Comment: `SetWindowText()` is defined either as `SetWindowTextW()` or as `SetWindowTextA()` depending on your project's settings. If the new app is Unicode either use `SetWindowTextA()` explicitly or define the strings as Unicode (eg L"GAME!"), or use the `_T()` macro, eg _T("GAME!") (this in theory would work in both ANSI and Unicode). The cast (in the SetWindowText() call) won't make the conversion for you.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I'd make that an answer.

Comment: Every cast is a lie. Once you remove them, the compiler will tell you what's wrong. [It’s okay to be contrary, but you need to be consistently contrary: Going against the ambient character set](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211210-00/?p=106021).

Answer (score 3):

Although the last revision will work in a Unicode project, it is still not very much OK. It's indeed kinda "Frankenstein", because it mixes types and definitions. `wchar_t` is a C++ type (albeit implementation-defined), while the whole `T` mechanism is Microsoft-specific and based on preprocessor defines. Depending on the compiler options T is defined as either W, for Unicode, or A (or nothing) for ANSI. This applies to types (eg `LPCTSTR`->`LPCWSTR/LPCSTR`) and functions (eg `SetWindowText()`->`SetWindowTextW()/SetWindowTextA()`). Also, why use a cast at all? Therefore, in order to be consistent I would suggest to modify your code as shown below:

**A. Explicit Unicode Implementation**

```
void CTICTACView::Game()
{
    CWnd* p_Wnd = GetParent();
    const wchar_t* capt = L"TIC TAC TOE"; // you could also use WCHAR
    const wchar_t* gm = L"GAME!";
    if (!game)
        p_Wnd->SetWindowTextW(capt);
    else
        p_Wnd->SetWindowTextW(gm);
}
```

The above code will also work even with the multibyte (ANSI) option, as all types and calls are explicitly Unicode. It will always call the wide version of `SetWindowText()` and pass a wide string. If the project is compiled with the multibyte character option, the function (not the compiler!) will convert the string to ANSI, based on the system's default codepage.

**B. Using the "T" (conditional) definitions**

```
void CTICTACView::Game()
{
    CWnd* p_Wnd = GetParent();
    const TCHAR* capt =_T("TIC TAC TOE"); // You could also use LPCTSTR instead of TCHAR*
    const TCHAR* gm = _T("GAME!");
    if (!game)
        p_Wnd->SetWindowText(capt);
    else
        p_Wnd->SetWindowText(gm);
}
```

The above code should work with both the Unicode and ANSI options. In the Unicode case the strings will be defined as wide-strings, and the wide version of `SetWindowText()` will be called, while in the ANSI case both the strings and the function call will be ANSI. No conversion will take place in either case.

Furthermore, the code could be consolidated quite a bit:

```
void CTICTACView::Game()
{
    GetParent()->SetWindowText(game ? _T("GAME!") : _T("TIC TAC TOE"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining the party with delay, I've been solving something similar - due to historical reasons had an ANSI window (registered by MFC via `::RegisterClassA`) that was uncapable of displaying Unicode character in its caption via `::SetWindowTextW` - the input Unicode was converted to ANSI before being sent to the window through its registered ANSI window procedure. I had to make a direct call to the window:

```
WCHAR unicode[80]; // populated with "Příšerně žluťoučký kůň"
::SendMessageW( hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)unicode );
```

The other solution in my case would be turning several projects to Unicode - which proved to be not so easy due to untyped pointers to strings (`PVOID`) and external dependencies (the '*Treat WChar_t as built-in type*' switch in the Settings).